# R Pi Samba mount error 112 (on an Zyxel NAS which had been mounting fine for 2yr using vers=1.0)

Tags: mount, raspberry-pi, samba, cifs

I have a raspberry pi 4 4gb which I've been using for 3y, initially as a Plex server and now as a backup file server. I have this old zyxel nsa310 NAS device that works very well up until now, with a 6TB drive. I had previously mounted it with the vers=1.0 but this no longer works.

The zyxel device has 1 share: "public"

Trying to mount it:

sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.2.17/public /media/NAS -o vers=1.0

Output:

Password for root@//192.168.2.17/public:
mount error: Server abruptly closed the connection.
This can happen if the server does not support the SMB version you are trying to use.
The default SMB version recently changed from SMB1 to SMB2.1 and above. Try mounting with vers=1.0.
mount error(112): Host is down
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)

when I ran dmesg

[ 5196.784338] CIFS: Attempting to mount //192.168.2.17/public
[ 5196.784429] CIFS: VFS: Use of the less secure dialect vers=1.0 is not recommended unless required for access to very old servers
[ 5196.836497] CIFS: VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -112

also the /etc/fstab entry

//192.168.2.17/public /media/NAS cifs username=admin,password=xx,uid=pi,gid=pi,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,vers=1.0 0 0

The background is that I had a lot of trouble 2y ago mounting this share, and worked out that the SMB vers=1.0 was needed. Now this no longer works. I realised yesterday when adding another drive. I can mount the share in windows if I add the SMB v1 optional feature.

I have tried editing the share in the Zyxel NSA310 management webpage, and changing it from private to public. I try all the different password options I can think of, nothing makes a difference.

Very occasionally, it mounts, and I managed to copy a few files, before dmesg gives a attempting to reconnect >180 second timeout

It gives the error and recommends that vers=1.0 be used but I have been using that all along. I have been trying to help myself for 2 days straight but now I don't know what else to try.

Any help / suggestions much appreciated. (I have cross posted to Reddit /raspberrypi without any luck.)